# What are "system design specifications" as the California labor code refers to them?

Tags: california, labor-law, salary

In California employment law, there is a term called "system design specifications." Attorneys have told me to ask technical I.T. people what this means as there is no legal definition for it.

An excerpt of the law (CA Labor Code Section 515.5) says this: "The design, development, documentation, analysis, creation, testing, or modification of computer systems or programs, including prototypes, based on and related to user or system design specifications."

I understand what it says except for "system design specifications." What are "system design specifications"?

Comment: If you're looking for "technical I.T. people", then Law.SE is not the place to ask

Answer (score 1):

If a word or phrase doesn't have a specific legal definition then it takes its simple English meaning.

"user or system design specifications" simply means working to a document (a specification) for the design of computer systems for back-end (systems) or front-end (user) uses.